# Detect Matching Sounds in Audio Stream

Tags: c++, audio, mp3

I'd like to compare the audio output from a PC game to known audio files (*.mp3 for example).

If the audio stream contains the recorded audio, I'd like to measure the amplitude of the matching audio in the left/right stereo channels. The goal is to determine the direction and distance of the sound (footsteps/gunshots).

It would also be a bonus to amplify the matching audio without affecting the rest of the audio stream.

Are there any open-source projects that would be a good reference? Any language (especially C++) would be great.

- Similar question using external hardware with a 3DS:
  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182370/arduino-recognizing-pre-recorded-sound-clips-from-an-audio-stream
- Phone dial pad tone detection in C++:
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/dtmf/?source=navbar

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast Audience Research Council (BARC) encodes TV channel audio with unique ID of the channel to identify the channel and measure the viewing time.

For example you can encode a tone with unique frequency for each audio. At the receiver multiple tone detectors using IC556 identifies the embedded tone. An Arduino can then send the identity to your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seccpur. I wouldn't mind using an Arduino - do you know of any open-source projects using audio watermarking with compressed audio formats like *.mp3? Also, would this require me to modify the game's audio files?

Comment: I had rigged up my own years back for autonomous tone based switching through satellite.i use a separate channel(ch3), hence not audible to the listener( channel 1 &2) , on the SDI .it's pretty simple to implement  but the setup could cost.

Comment: Also put the query on electrical engineering @ stackexchange as the implementation is likely to be hardware based.